# Is there a way to use tf.keras.model.predict within a tf.data pipeline?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a trained model that I would like to employ in the `tf.data` pipeline for a second model. When I try to do this, I get a `ValueError: Unknown graph. Aborting.` I don't know quite what to make of this error message.

My code looks something like this:

```
def load_data(..., model):
    # code to load an image
    files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(file_list)
    images = files.map(load_image_from_file) 

    def pass_image_through_model(img):
        return model.predict(img, steps=1)

    dataset = images.map(pass_image_through_model)
    return dataset
```

What is wrong with this? The error I get is:

```
    /home/.../code/dataloader.py:236 pass_image_through_model  *
        return model.predict(img, steps=1)
    /home/.../anaconda3/envs/masters/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py:1013 predict
        use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    /home/.../anaconda3/envs/masters/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py:728 predict
        callbacks=callbacks)
    /home/.../anaconda3/envs/masters/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py:189 model_iteration
        f = _make_execution_function(model, mode)
    /home/.../anaconda3/envs/masters/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py:571 _make_execution_function
        return model._make_execution_function(mode)
    /home/.../anaconda3/envs/masters/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py:2131 _make_execution_function
        self._make_predict_function()
    /home/.../anaconda3/envs/masters/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py:2121 _make_predict_function
        **kwargs)
    /home/.../anaconda3/envs/masters/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py:3760 function
        return EagerExecutionFunction(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, name=name)
    /home/.../anaconda3/envs/masters/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py:3644 __init__
        raise ValueError('Unknown graph. Aborting.')

    ValueError: Unknown graph. Aborting.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to tackle this is to pass the input to the model directly, rather than using `model.predit` method. The reason for this is that `model.predict` returns a `numpy.ndarray`. This causes an error because `tf.data` uses graph execution, which means it's best to have any operation input AND output a tensor within that graph.

Below is a quick working example of this.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Create example model
inputs = tf.keras.Input((1,))
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, out)

def map_fn(row):
    return model(row)


# Create some input data 
a = tf.constant([1, 2])

# Create the dataset
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a).batch(1)
model_mapped_ds = ds.map(lambda x: map_fn(x))

for el in model_mapped_ds:
    print(el)
```

Finally, below is what it would look like in your usage.

```py
def pass_image_through_model(img):
    return model(img) # this returns a tensor 

@tf.function
def load_data(..., model):
    # code to load an image
    files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(file_list).batch(1) # Don't forget batch size!
    images = files.map(load_image_from_file) 

    dataset = images.map(pass_image_through_model)
    return dataset
```

Comment: This works, but the load_data function now adds considerable overhead to the training process, approximately an order of magnitude slowdown as compared to doing a cheap tensorflow operation. Is there more efficient way to pass input through a model?

Comment: Another way is to add the `@tf.function` decorator to the load_data function. I'll edit the post to add this.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is maybe silent if it is your first time dealing with `tf.data.Dataset()` object.

All the operations in `tf.data.Dataset()` are actually executed in graph mode and you cannot use any functions outside those predefined in `tf.*`.

The only way you can mix arbitrary Python code with your `tf.data.Dataset()` is to use `tf.py_function()`, otherwise an error will be thrown.

Please bear in mind that mixing Python code with optimised `tf.data.Dataset()` code will lead to a decrease in time performance.

The only way to test is to retrieve your dataset, use `as_numpy_iterator()` to fetch your data and predict with your model, therefore outside of the mapping process.